# Sending KeyboardInterrupt to first python program with a button in the second GUI python program

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, subprocess, keyboardinterrupt

The first program can only be stopped by Keyboard Interrupt (Ctrl + C). If the program is killed, its of no use to me. I want to know what code can be used with the button so that a Keyboard Interrupt command is executed to the first program and my program stops.

I have 2 buttons. One for starting the first program, one to stop the first program by sending Ctrl+C to it.

```
def callPython():
    global proc
    proc = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'MPython.py'])

def killtask():
    if proc and proc.poll() is None:
        print('killing process ...')
        proc.kill()


StartButton = Button(frame2, text='Start the Reading', width=20, height=3, command=callPython)
StartButton.pack()

StopButton = Button(frame2, text='Stop the Reading', width= 20, height= 3, command=killtask)
StopButton.pack()
```

This is my code as of now. What change can be done to this?

Comment: Read up on [Tutorial - 6.1.1. Executing modules as scripts](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#executing-modules-as-scripts)